# Find all files that have been last modified on a specific day - like Monday?

Tags: find, date

So I want to use `find` to return a list of all .html files in a given directory that have been last modified on a Monday. How can I do this?

Comment: You really mean by a given day of the week and not by some actual date, right?

Comment: Is this an [XY problem](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=542341), troll question, or is there a legitimate reason why you need to find all files modified on any day that happened to be a monday?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure of a good way to do this directly using only `find` or similar, but you can use `find` and `grep`:

```
find -printf '%Tw:%h/%f\0' | grep -z '^1:'
```

Since it's `find`, you can of course combine other flags:

```
find -name '*.html' -type f -printf '%Tw:%h/%f\0' | grep -z '^1:'
```

to get only files ending with `.html`.

### Explanation

Here is my test directory:

```
$ ls -la
total 68
drwxr-xr-x  2 anthony anthony  4096 Mar 24 17:53 .
drwxrwxrwt 98 root    root    61440 Mar 24 17:55 ..
-rw-r--r--  1 anthony anthony     0 Mar 24 17:53 monday
-rw-r--r--  1 anthony anthony     0 Mar 23 11:12 sunday
```

`find`'s `-printf` argument takes a format string. Here, %T means last modified time. The `w` after it means the day of the week, from 0 (Sunday) through 6 (Saturday). You can get the name with `a` (abbreviated: Mon) or `A` (full: Monday), but those are locale-specific. `:` gives a literal `:`. `%h/%f` is the path and file name. `\0` null-separates the entries (like `-print0` does).

So that prints out something like `1:./.<NULL>0:./sunday<NULL>1:./monday<NULL>`, which if you replace the NULL with newline for readability with `tr '\0' '\n'` is:

```
1:./.
0:./sunday
1:./monday
```

Then `grep -z '^1:'` looks for things starting with 1:, which is Monday.

Answer (score 2):

You can get `ls` to output dates in a custom format

`ls --time-style=+%A *.html | grep " Monday "`

Assuming " Monday " is not in any file name.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `find` + `grep` + `date`  Command:

```
find /path -iname "*.html" -printf "%TY%Tm%Td\t%p\n" | \
grep $(date -dlast-monday +%Y%m%d)
```

if you want to print only file name then use:

```
find /path -iname "*.html" -printf "%TY%Tm%Td\t%p\n" | \
awk "/$(date -dlast-monday +%Y%m%d)"'/{print $NF}'
```

OR

```
 find /path -iname "*.html" -printf "%Ta\t%p\n" | awk '/Mon/{print $NF}'
```

Answer (score 1):

Though I find your question highly suspect, the answer is:

```
find ./ -type f -name '*.html' -printf "%Ta %p\n" | grep '^Mon' | sed 's:^Mon ::'
```

Which will find all files ending in `.html` that were last modified on any Monday in human history, according to the current timezone set on the server.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `find` with `stat` to find all files that have a modification timestamp on a Monday as follows:

```
find . -type f -exec stat -t %a  {} \; | awk 'match($10, /"Mon"/) {print $16}'
```

The `find` command will find all files and stat them which will be piped to the `awk` filter. `awk` will match field number 10 which is the modification time of file with string `"Mon"` to extract the files modified on Mondays. The `print $16` statement will print the filename. you can remove `$16` to print all fields or use any number to print selected fields.

Example output of first part (on OS X ):

```
$ cd /usr ; find . -type file -exec stat -t %a  {} \;
```

> 16777218 20556154 -rwxr-xr-x 1 root wheel 0 19600 "Mon" "Thu" "Thu" "Sat" 4096 16 0x20 ./bin/du
>
> 16777218 20547205 -rwxr-xr-x 1 root wheel 0 14256 "Wed" "Thu" "Thu" "Wed" 4096 16 0x20 ./bin/dwarfdump
>
> 16777218 20586248 -rwxr-xr-x 2 root wheel 0 925 "Fri" "Thu" "Thu" "Sun" 4096 0 0x20 ./bin/easy_install

Comment: That badly breaks if your file names have spaces (or several other special characters) in them.

Comment: On my OS X, the filename gets printed last so, seems to be working for filenames with spaces.

Comment: Interesting, here (on Linux, with GNU Coreutils), the file name is printed first...